# How do i find the sum of an array with a restriction?

Tags: javascript

Lets say i wanted to find the sum of all numbers within an array that are equal to or higher than 15. What would the best practice and performance be to solve the issue?
The code underneath finds the sum of the whole array.

```
<script>
    
var list = [15, 5, 5, 5, 15];


// Getting sum of numbers
var sum = list.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}, 0);



console.log(sum); // Prints: 25

 </script>
```

Comment: `list.filter(num=>num>=15).reduce(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array.filter()`

```js
var list = [15, 5, 5, 5, 15];

// Getting sum of numbers
var sum = list.filter(a => a >= 15).reduce((a, b) => a+b);

console.log(sum); // Prints 30
```

Comment: `=>` represents an arrow function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. `>=` is equal to or more than.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = [15, 5, 5, 5, 15];

var sum = list.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + (b >= 15 ? b : 0);
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

If you do not want to double loop, you could just use a conditional in the reduce.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var cars = [1, 12, 31];
var sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if(cars[i] > 10)
    {
        sum += cars[i]
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do forEach

```
ar list = [15, 5, 5, 5, 15];
var sum = 0;

list.forEach((i) => {
  if (i >= 15) {


    sum += i;
  }
});

console.log(sum)
```